# Why is it not possible to signal a task from inside an NMI handler using kernel services?

Tags: embedded, rtos

While reading through uCOS-II documentation, I read that one can't use kernel-provided mechanisms to signal a task from inside an NMI, and I am not clear why.

Thank you.

Edit:

Source: uc/OS-II The Real Time Kernel User's Manual, Chapter 2: Real Time Systems Concepts, Page 86:

> When you are servicing an NMI, you cannot use kernel services to
>   signal a task because NMIs cannot be disabled to access critical
>   sections of code. However you can still pass parameters to and from
>   the NMI.

Comment: generally, NMI is reserved for "things have gone really really bad", so there's no real value in supporting kernel services because the machine is in an unrecoverable state.

Comment: @RussSchultz : Possibly true in some cases, but not necessarily so, and that is not the reason given in the uC/OS-II documentation.  There it describes the use of NMI where extremely low latency is required.  On most targets "things have gone really bad" handling is better done using exception handlers - though you might use an NMI to handle a watchdog timer rather then a direct reset I suppose.

Comment: Add a clear citation and/or quote of the documentation you are referring to and I think this would be a good question and should not be closed or down-voted.  Your confusion is perhaps clear when you read the documentation I think you are referring to, but without that it is not.

Comment: @Clifford: Thank you. I understand why my confusion will not seem obvious. I'll cite the para from the source, though you have nailed it correctly below and your answer makes sense to me.

Comment: What you can often do is set a 'normal' software interrupt enable that will then run when the NMI returns.  That interrupt can then set an event/semaphore/whatever and so cause a thread to become ready.  You could make it a high-priority thread.  I know that's not the same as a direct NMI-invoked reschedule but, as others have commented, that is unsafe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The book *MicroC/OS-II The Real Time Kernel 2nd ed.* explains the reasoning (albeit rather briefly):

> **2.31 Nonmaskable Interrupts**
>
> *[...]* When you are servicing an NMI, you cannot use kernel services to signal a task because NMIs cannot be disabled to access critical sections of code. *[...]*

It is perhaps not obvious why this might be a problem, but if a thread enters a critical section and the NMI occurs, calling a kernel service that signals a task will cause the scheduler to be invoked and will cause a context switch within the interrupted critical section.

Comment: @krishnagaurav I was not aware that votes were delayed - are you sure?  You might also choose to accept the answer.

Comment: I did not mean that vote was delayed, rather it does not reflect publicly as my reputation has not yet reached 15 (I am a new user).